# jQuery script not running in JSF page using ui:composition

Tags: jquery, html, jsf-2

I'm trying to get my jQuery code to run in my JSF page which uses `ui:composition`. I've tried so many different things including putting in `<head>` tags, `<h:head>` tags, eventually I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000101/how-to-add-different-javascripts-on-a-page-when-using-uicomposition) and so tried using the solution there, but to no avail.

At the top of the script is an `alert("ready")` so I'll know that the script has loaded, but so far I've not gotten it to work. The jQuery code itself works fine (I've tested it in a JSFiddle and on a normal HTML page).

Any suggestions would be helpful!

---

### My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("ready");
    ...
    ...
});
```

---

### This is my JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                template="./_Template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="script"><h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-2.1.3.min.js" target="head" /> </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="script"><h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-ui.min.js" target="head"/> </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="script"><h:outputScript library="javascript" name="1.js"/> </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="top">
        <h1>Weather App</h1>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="left">
        <h3>Navigation</h3>
        ...
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        <form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="search_results.html">
            <label for="searchBox">Search</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString" />
            <button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Submit</button>
        </form>      
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've there three `<ui:define>` with the same `name`. That's not right. Use one.

```
<ui:define name="script">
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-2.1.3.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-ui.min.js" />
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="1.js" />
</ui:define>
```

This assumes that you've an `<ui:insert name="script">` inside `<h:head>`.

The answer you found makes use of JSF-feature to auto-relocate the script into the `<h:head>` via `target="head"`. This way you can just put them anywhere in the composition. For example, inside `<ui:define name="content">`.

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-2.1.3.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jquery-ui.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="1.js" target="head" />
    ...
</ui:define>
```

This way you don't need the `<ui:insert name="script">` anymore.

#### See also:

- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `library="javascript"` is a red alarm. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) and act accordingly.

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:outputScript name="javascript/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="javascript/jquery-ui.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript name="javascript/1.js" target="head" />
    ...
</ui:define>
```