# Add Javascript to included JSF page?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I got a `MainPage.xhtml` which includes a lot of other xhtmls like:

```
<ui:include src="/pages/includes/included1.xhtml"
                    id="included1ID"/>
<ui:include src="/pages/includes/included2.xhtml"
                    id="included2ID"/>
```

... and so on.

There is some logic behind it which included page will be loaded, works fine.
I want to write some Javascript in the included pages which runs immediately as the page loads (for example in the `included1.xthml`).

I tried adding this section right after the `<ui:composition>` tag:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript>
          .
          .
        some JS
          .
          .
    </h:outputScript>
</h:head>
```

It works fine if I use it in a NOT included page, but doesn't work on included ones.
Is there any way to add my JS to those pages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add different javascripts on a page when using ui:composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000101/how-to-add-different-javascripts-on-a-page-when-using-uicomposition)

Comment: It's definitely not a duplicate. I have no problem adding any JS to my ui:composition but to another included page.

Comment: It for 100% sure IS a duplicate... you cannot add a head in a composite and have it used in another page. See the duplicate

Comment: So basically it is not possible what I want to do, right?

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible how you try to do it is not. Please read the duplicate correctly... put the script tag inside the composition add a `target="head"` to it and don't wrap it in an `h:head`